# Django tutorial error: "TypeError at /admin/ - 'set' object is not reversible"

Tags: python, django

I am going through an official Django tutorial called "Writing your first Django app" and am currently at part 2. Here is the URL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/

When trying to access the admin panel at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, as per the instructions, I receive the following error:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Django Version: 2.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  241.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  213.                 if request.path == reverse('admin:logout', current_app=self.name):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  58.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in app_dict
  512.             self._populate()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _populate
  463.                     url_pattern._populate()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _populate
  446.             for url_pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/
Exception Value: 'set' object is not reversible
```

I am on a Mac with Python 3 installed. I looked up all other similar questions for this error and none of the answers there heleped me, as my code seems to be correct

Here is my urls.py code

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('polls/', include('polls.urls'))
]
```

And here is the app list from settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Do you know what could be wrong here?

Comment: What's in `polls.urls`?

Comment: That was the culprit:

```python
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = {
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
}
```

I switched from {} to [] and now everything works. Didn't realize that this app would also break the site admin interface. Thank you!